# Need to reinstall Web Tools 2012.2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

My Visual Studio LESS compiler has stopped working, so I was going to try to reinstall Web Tools 2012.2 to see if it would come back to life.  However, the Web Platform Installer 4.5 tells me it's already installed with no option to reinstall, repair, uninstall, etc.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the installers can be found on Hanselman's blog.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleasedASPNETAndWebTools20122InContext.aspx